# CUDA shared memory cannot be allocated

Tags: c, memory, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm writing CUDA kernel code which uses shared memory, but have trouble to declare
shared memory variables.

It happens when I try to allocate multiple shared memory statically as follows.

```
__global__
void kernel_func(float *global_matrix) {
    __shared__ float sm_mat1[4][4];
    __shared__ float sm_mat2[6][6];
    __shared__ float sm_mat3[3][3][3];

    if ( blockIdx.x==0 && blockIdx.y==0 && theradIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.y==0 )
        printf("sizeof(sm_mat1)=%d, sizeof(sm_mat2)=%d, sizeof(sm_mat3)=%d.\n",
                    sizeof(sm_mat1), sizeof(sm_mat2), sizeof(sm_mat3));

    ...
}
```

However, when I execute, it output weird message as follows.

```
sizeof(sm_mat1)=64, sizeof(sm_mat2)=0, sizeof(sm_mat3)=128
```

It seems 2nd matrix is not allocated, and 3rd matrix is allocated as 2nd.
Actually, accessing 2nd matrix does not work correctly. (cannot read/write data).

I'm using a GTX 480, and cuda2.0.
(I'm printing message using compile option `-arch=sm_20`).

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Operator [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns not `int` but `std::size_t`.
So when you send its result to printf on systems where `sizeof(size_t) == 8` and `sizeof(int) == 4` and try to print it with `%d` one result of `sizeof` will be split into two halves that will be printed by consecutive `%d` specifiers. Zero placed instead of the second specifier is the top half of the first sizeof operator result.

To correct the output value, you can explicitly cast `sizeof` result to int or try `%ld` or `%lld` specifiers.

But i also can't reproduce the bug with incorrect second array size.

Comment: Good point. This is the correct answer. The error is on 64 bit platforms only, as `sizeof(size_t)` is `8` and is interpreted as 2 separate int values by `%d` format specifier.